# Como atribuir valor com jQuery a um textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Eu tenho um formulário de planos, e gostaria que ao clicar em adquirir, ele já preencher uma breve mensagem no  do formulário.
Estou tentando dessa maneira, porém não retorna valores

```js
window.onload = function (){

var mensagem = document.getElementById('mensagem');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var assinatura = '\n\nParabéns!!\nEscolheu o plano basic..'

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  mensagem.value += assinatura;

});
}
```

```html
<form>
      <textarea id="name" name="testa"></textarea>
      <button id="teste" type="button">Testando</button>
</form>
```

<sup>(***Lembrando que o trecho acima é um teste apenas***)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Sim, mas, você não colocou os nomes corretamente o [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) pega o elemento pela configuração do `id`, ***exemplo***:

***Html:***

```
<button id="btn" />
```

***Javascript:***

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn"); // btn é o id do button
```

Agora com as modificações no seu código:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var mensagem = document.getElementById('name');
  var button = document.getElementById('teste');
  var assinatura = 'Parabéns!!\nEscolheu o plano basic..'
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    mensagem.value = assinatura;
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
      <textarea id="name" name="testa"></textarea>
      <button id="teste" type="button">Testando</button>
</form>
```

***Observação:*** no seu código você colocou `id="name"` e fez a busca `document.getElementById('mensagem')` e no botão se colocou no `id="teste"` e fez a busca `document.getElementById('button')`, ou seja, errou o nome pelo qual deveria fazer a referencia no seu código [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

<sup>***Referencia:***</sup>

- [MDN web docs - document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [MDN web docs - addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener)